# jquery ajax store variable and then retrieve later on

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables

Hi i am using jquery and ajax to retrieve the user id of the logged in user, Im saving this into a variable as I want to be able to do some logic with it later on. however I am having trouble accessing it. My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var taskBoard = {
       fetch: function (url, data) {

        $('.loading-icon').fadeIn();
        $('.task_board').addClass('loading');


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (json) {
                $('.loading-icon').fadeOut();
                $('#task_board').html($(json.data.taskBoard));
                $('.task_board').removeClass('loading');
                $('.update-results').hide();

            } // end success
        }); //end ajax
    }, //end fetch function

    authUser: function (url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (json) {
                $.each($(json), function (index, item) {
                    taskBoard.storeUser(item.id);
                });


            } // end success
        }); //end ajax

    }, //end authUser function

    storeUser: function (param) {
        var authUserId = param;
        return param;
        // if I do an alert here the correct user id is returned.
    },

} //end var taskBoard

      //However if I do an alert here  outside of the var taskBoard I get an undefined. 

     alert(taskBoard.storeUser());
 });
```

Any ideas how I can get this globally assigned variable outside of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
storeUser: function (param) {
    var authUserId = param;
    return param;
    // if I do an alert here the correct user id is returned.
},
```

change to this:

```
authUserId : null,
storeUser: function (param) {
    if (param)
    {
        this.authUserId = param;
    }
    return this.authUserId;
},
```

Now the var `authUserId` will be stored as a property in the `taskBoard` object.
When param is undefined it will return the value unupdated if not it will update it first and then returns it.

A more elegant solution would be to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) here.

Delete the `storeUser` property and after the declaration of the `taskBoard` object add this:

```
Object.defineProperty(taskBoard, "storeUser", {
    get : function(){ return this.StoreUserVar; },
    set : function(value){ this.StoreUserVar = value; }
});
```

Now you can assign the userid with:

```
taskBoard.storeUser = item.id;

//-------- taskBoard object
        success: function (json) {
            $.each($(json), function (index, item) {
                taskBoard.storeUser = item.id;
                doOtherFunction();
            });
//--------

function doOtherFunction()
{
    //the callback function fired from the success.
    alert(taskBoard.storeUser); //this will alert with the value set.
}
```

Comment: I this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the var authUserId line

Comment: thanks how do I access this variable as doing this returns null: alert(taskBoard.authUserId);

Comment: thanks for the new update that looks cool. if I use that how can I access this variable?

Comment: Because the variable is still `null` then using the initial value. You are using an Ajax call. Your variable will be filled when the ajax request has completed. You should add a callback function to the success part of the `authUser` function.

Comment: Accessing the variable with Object.defineProperty is simple: `taskBoard.storeUser`. Here also you need to keep in mind the fact that the data will only be assigned when the success function is called.

Comment: ok i see, this `taskBoard.storeUser` returns undefined. Is this because I need to do a callback? Are you able to demonstrate how I can do this?

Comment: is this variable not accessible though the doOtherFunction()? e.g. if I  change the alert to return and then try to access via alert(doOtherFuntion()); this just returns the code of that function

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need a global variable then declare that variable before the document.ready, since variables defined in this function are only valid in this function

[Javascript Scope Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)